# How to debug this code calculating cosine similarity of two unicode files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have adapted some code I found in a NLTK tutorial for calculating the cosine similarity of documents, to apply to two unicode files. I actually have 5 files to work on but am starting with code that will work on two small sample files. However, I haven't been able to actually calculate the cosine similarity. This code produces the following error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`.

I have tried this:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
    tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english',
    encoding='utf-8', decode_error='ignore',
    strip_accents='unicode',lowercase='false', norm='l1')

def cosine_sim(token_dict):
    tfs = [tfidf.fit_transform(w) for w in token_dict]
    return ((tfs[0] * tfs0[0].T).A)[0,1]
```

But this returns the following error: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1`.

I have also tried coverting the tfs list to a numpy array, transposing it manually and then doing the cosine calculation, but I get an error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`.

```
import nltk
import string
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import codecs

path = 'C:/Users/Me/Dropbox/DocumentSimilarityTesting'
token_dict = {}
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        shakes = codecs.open(os.path.join(path,file), "r",encoding='utf-8',
        errors='ignore')
        text = shakes.read()
        lowers = text.lower()
        remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in
        string.punctuation)
        no_punctuation = [lowers.translate(remove_punctuation_map)]
        token_dict[file] = no_punctuation

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english',
encoding='utf-8', decode_error='ignore',
strip_accents='unicode',lowercase='false', norm='l1')
def cosine_sim(token_dict):
    tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(token_dict.values())
    return ((tfs * tfs.T).A)[0,1]
```

I am expecting a value that is the cosine similarity of the two documents, but I am getting an error message. I can print our the elements of the tfs list that this code produces, but it seems my code cannot transpose the list and calculate the cosine similarity.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: Why are you using python 2.7 when you can use 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first exception `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1` I'm assuming that `((tfs[0] * tfs0[0].T).A)[0,1]` is the culprit. Try to explore the contents of `(tfs[0] * tfs0[0].T).A` and see how many dimensions and elements does it contain. That should give you an idea of why you might be out of bounds for that matrix.

For the transposition with the exception `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'` only the code can tell the truth I'm afraid. (which we haven't seen in the question)

As for the last exception `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`, I'm assuming that:

```
text = shakes.read()
lowers = text.lower()
```

are causing the problem, and presumably the `shakes.read()` returns a list rather than a string. Do make sure you know what data you receive there.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. In the loop, the shake.read and text.lower, as well as the lowers.translate were returning lists instead of strings. When I converted the list to a string before storing in the dict, this solved the problem. I appreciate you taking the time to help!